# Is SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 still the latest version and is it compatible with Chrome/ChromeDriver Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (64-bit)?

Tags: vba, selenium

I'm using VBA in Microsoft Access 365 and want to use it for web automation (filling web forms and getting the resulting information using variables)

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like SeleniumBasic is installing an outdated ChromeDriver.exe? (2.21.371459)

*Error Screenshot*
[image: Error Screenshot]

My current version of Chrome is: Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I'm reading all sorts of information about IDE's etc, and it's all a bit overwhelming! :(

To test this theory, I went ahead and replaced the ChromeDriver.exe file in C:\Program Files (x86)\SeleniumWrapper with the newer, compatible version # 102.0.5005.61

The code now throws another error

[image: Error Screenshot #2]

but at least it's now showing the correct driver. The error information screenshot also says that "DevToolsActivePort file does not exist". What??? How do I set that up? As I said, overwhelming.

Comment: Did you make sure you downloaded the same driver version number as your current chrome version?

Comment: Yes, I have now… and it works. Next question: is there some sort of “web recorder “ that can record your input and save it as script? I was using OpenTwebst for that, but it only works with IE… which makes it all but useless!

Comment: Not that I know of, you have to go into the HTML of the webpage and find your identifiers (Ids, Class Names, Names, Tags, and XPaths) on your own.

Comment: Sadly there is no web recorder that will be perfect for your use case. Primarily because of the language. There are recorders like Katalon but the export languages do not include VBA. Furthermore, using easy to translate export languages like python suffer from the fact that selenium basic has a lot less functionality "out-of-the-box" so you would end up having to figure out workarounds, if/where possible, using custom JavaScript and executeScript method of webdriver instance.

Comment: That said, automation with selenium basic takes no more than a couple of hours to get a reasonable grip on. Reading html and understanding css selectors/basic JavaScript will take additional time. These are very good tutorials: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/videos/vba-scrape-websites/selenium-get-started/

Comment: Your two error screenshots are completely identical. I can confirm that SeleniumBasic v.2.0.9.0 from 2016 absolutely still works on Windows 10 here in late 2022. 
Difficult to say why you're experiencing these problems when you're not sharing any code and more specific details about your setup. Very bad if you want help from others. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.Start` before using the `.Get`. Yes, this vba version of selenium hasn't had regular (or any) updates in like 8 years so it's not perfect. You have to keep your drivers up to date etc. You'll have a much better experience if you use Selenium with Python or Java.

```
Dim sel As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim url As String

sel.Start "chrome", "http://google.com"
sel.Get "/"
```

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded a version of Chromedriver that matches my Chrome browser, and it seems to work… for a few seconds, then the browser closes. I have read that this is caused because the driver goes “out of scope” when the procedure ends. The cure is to “Dim” the driver in the main header section, Right after “Option Explicit” I haven’t tested this yet.